# Word that could use for " reaching to the point where one is referring quickly"

Tags: word-usage, word-request

I am looking for a word which could give the meaning of

> "reaching to the point where one is referring quickly"

like if some one saying something with an intention which is not know if we go by their words, like they are referring some hidden/indirect meaning

Comment: I think you should clarify whether you actually mean an intentionally hidden meaning, or just an indirect meaning. Depending on that clarification, possible answers are **idiom**, **jargon**, or **code**, if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: Something like "get to the point"?

Comment: or ''cutting to the chase'' (in context: 'cut to the chase')

Comment: I flagged this question for closure because I can't tell what it means. The existing answer may be good, but it's impossible to tell whether it actually addresses what the question is asking. I think the OP may mean "inferring" or "implying" rather than "referring," Anyway, the question is old and Community bumped it. There's already one unanswered comment asking for clarification, and I doubt more clarification is forthcoming.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's one word for that. To someone who seems like they mean something other than what they're saying, I might intensely look them in the eye and say:

> What are you implying?

or

> What are you suggesting?

or

> What do you mean to say?

If I wanted to be a little more direct, I might say:

> Hey, be straight with me.